# How can I Code A multiple search?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, select, where-clause

I got a Categories table and people need to say: (Yes, my code working by words :) )

`'list books and pencils'`

But Another day, they want to say:

```
'list books, pencils, notebooks and papers'
```

I'm using **stored procedures at mssql.**
Or I don't want to use 4 parameters, and limit the user. I will use this solution at many pages so I'm searching for perfect solution.

Thanks..

**edit:**

I don't want to parse it in stored procedure for performance and security, but if it is the only way, say me, I can understand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the values in as xml or string to the stored procedure and have some logic in the stored procedure to parse the values.

Comment: Yeah I thinked that, But is it the best solution? I want more performance :) And I'm afraid of sql injection. Is it safe for sql injection?

Comment: SQL injection depends on how you pass in your the string. you'll be using parameters when passing values to stored procedure so you should be safe. you can have some validate the parameter either in code or in store procedure.

Comment: I will send @statement="1,4,7" and mssql will parse it, maybe add an array. Then my query is will be "where ID=1 or Id=4 or Id=7". Is it true?

Comment: yes, I was thinking to do something like that. Another way you can do is to parse values in your code, then execute the stored procedure for each value like once for 1, then for 4 and then for 7

Comment: I want to do your second way, but stored procedures parameters are identifying at first. How Can procedure take it?

Comment: I didn't quite get your last question. You can do something link string.split(',' arrayData) in code and parse the resulted array into int. you then make stored procedure to accept an integer as parameter and execute it for each value. so if you have 3 values, you would have to run it three times.